# Error creating an EKS Cluster, name and argument cannot be used at the same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, eksctl

After trial and error I was able to finally get an EKS cluster up and running and deploy some software through a Helm Chart. After bringing the cluster down I tried to create a new cluster following the same exact process and am hitting an error upon executing the **eksctl create** command. Any idea what causes this error; I've been unable to find any detailed information regarding this error.

```
eksctl create cluster \
--name ${eksclustername} \
--version 1.21 \
--node-type r5d.4xlarge \
--nodes 5 \
--nodes-min 0 \
--nodes-max 5 \
--nodegroup-name ${eksnodegropname} \
--region ${eksregion}
```

**`Error: --name=My-Cluster and argument us-east-2 cannot be used at the same time`**

Comment: Can you dump eksregion variable? I suppose it contains some wild data.

Comment: echo $eksregion

us-east-2

Comment: Seems this was a problem of my own creation.  The first run I did not use a variable name for the nodegroup-name; upon further examination of my script I see that I spelled my variable name incorrectly in the assignment, i.e. eksnodegropname vs eksnodegroupname.  At least now when I see this error I'll have some ideas what's causing it.